# Updating BIOS on DOS

Tags: bios, upgrade, uefi

I am using a Gigabyte GA-Z68MA-D2H-B3 motherboard on my computer. I wanted to migrate from Award BIOS to UEFI. I downloaded the binary file from the Gigabyte product page, but when I tried to run, it says the the executable is not compatible with 64 bit versions of Windows. (I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits).

I sent an e-mail to Gigabyte, and today I received an answer:

> Thank you for your kindly mail and inquiry. About the issue you mentioned, to update BIOS, you should be able to update it under DOS mode. After flash BIOS to UEFI, a warning message will appear: “Please shutdown and unplug power cord then plug back in order to complete BIOS update” Need to follow this instruction to complete the update.

I don't know how to enter the DOS mode. Please, could anyone explain me?

Comment: If you don't know DOS, it would really **not** be a good idea to update your BIOS.

Comment: why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I have previously updated my BIOS, this will not be the first time, but everything worked ok...

Comment: But I don't know how to enter DOS mode...

Comment: @Victor - It means you use a bootable flash drive.

Comment: Nice, good to know of a motherboard manufacturer that enables users to do what I had asked about here: [Is is possible to update BIOS to UEFI?](http://superuser.com/questions/494303/is-is-possible-to-update-bios-to-uefi)

Comment: If my question helps you, then you cann upvote it :d

Comment: No, I don't have that MB so it doesn't specifically help me, but you have my vote nevertheless. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too large to put in as a comment in to [Dave Rook's answer](https://superuser.com/a/527084/25625), but windows does not have the option to make a bootable floppy in the newer versions of windows, or you may not even have a floppy drive to copy the file to at all.

You can make a bootable USB drive that acts just like a bootable floppy

Here is a snippit from a email I got while working with a different company that I needed to be in DOS mode to run their recovery tool.

> Making a boot USB key . . .
>
> If your system can boot a USB device, here is some basic instructions
>   for making a bootable USB key.
>
> HP makes an easy to use utility called HP USB Disk Format Tool, which
>   includes a "Create a DOS Startup Disk" option.  It's available for
>   free download at http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197
>   along with the Windows 98/DOS boot files
>   http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=196.
>
> You can use the HP tool and point it at a directory where you unzip
>   the DOS boot files and it automatically builds a bootable DOS USB key
>   using those files.

Once you have your USB bootable drive just follow the [directions in the PDF](http://www.gigabyte.com/webpage/20/images/flashbios_dos.pdf) (starting right after the format step (Section Two)) but use the usb drive wherever it says to use a floppy.

---

Here is an [additional link](http://bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm) to instructions for making the boot USB stick, it also has it's own links to copies of the two files if the first two links in my answer do not work (Thank you [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek) for the extra link).

Comment: http://www.bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm here's another mirror to it

Comment: I made it. successfuly. Now I have UEFI on my motherboard. Thank you!

Comment: is making a bootable usb with freedos using rufus / unetbootin different from HP usb disk format tool?

Answer (score 2):

I think this (large) Gigabyte document will help you.

http://www.gigabyte.com/webpage/20/images/flashbios_dos.pdf

There is just too much information in the document to copy the relevant part into my post, sorry for a link only answer.

Comment: don't worry :). I will try to find the relevant part by myself.