# How do I find the storage capacity of the E²PROM chip on my motherboard? How much space is needed for UEFI to be implemented?

Tags: motherboard, bios, uefi, eeprom

I'm looking at a solution for upgrading BIOS to UEFI on a motherboard that doesn't natively support UEFI. Another user, Rod Smith, replied to a question as to how this would be done stating: "It's theoretically possible, and may be semi-practical on some computers. What you'd need to do is to merge CoreBoot with a TianoCore UEFI payload." and then goes on to say: "...the major obstacle is one of the size of the EEPROM chips on most motherboards." This is why I ask for this information. It appears to be a more viable solution than booting UEFI from a hard drive (which Rod Smith has a very detailed article on.)

The aforementioned reply can be found here: [Is it possible to update BIOS to UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/494303/is-is-possible-to-update-bios-to-uefi)

Comment: First check if your mainboard is supported by coreboot, not a lot are.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem like it is. You weren't kidding when you said few were supported. I'm not surprised though, my motherboard came with my HP PC that I bought almost four years ago now. it's some unknown brand and was mediocre in those days (it's not even a full ATX.) I supposed that I will have to go the DUET route. The article specifies that data may become corrupted. This doesn't physically endanger any hardware though, right? I have a 3TB hard drive than I'm not using (because BIOS doesn't support 3TB and I really don't wan to partition it), so I wouldn't mind corrupted data on it.