# I cannot boot Linux Mint usb alongside Windows 10

Tags: linux, boot, windows-10, bios, multi-boot

I am having trouble with my HP dm4-3050us. This computer originally came installed with Windows 7 and runs Legacy BIOS. I had no issues dual booting OS's when Windows 7 was installed, however upgrading to Windows 10 has brought on some complications. The boot order does not work, no matter what I put the primary as, it boots Windows 10 regardless.

Loading the 'select boot device' during POST does not work either, since the only options available are the HDD and internal CD/DVD. I've tried disabling fast startup, though that hasn't helped either. The BIOS doesn't help much further outside of the boot order, since the options are very limited. I've considered possibly upgrading to UEFI, however that's only led to headache on whether or not it can even be done on my machine, not to mention the fact that I'm not sure if it's even necessary to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've read that it can be done on particular machines, though resorting to it was more of an act of desperation. Was hoping it could somehow be possible, oh well.
http://superuser.com/questions/494303/is-is-possible-to-update-bios-to-uefi

Comment: You can't upgrade to "UEFI" either your system already supports it and your using legacy mode, or you are out of luck, in either case you running in compatibility mode isn't the reason for your problem.