# Can I upgrade my BIOS(LENOVO DPK21A) to UEFI?

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a Lenovo Ideacentre K330B running Windows 10 Home and I want to change it's BIOS to UEFI. It has a Lenovo motherboard. Here are some specs -

- BIOS Version/Date: "LENOVO DPK21A, 8/8/2011"
- Bios Mode: Legacy

I've been searching around the internet for a straightforward way to do this but haven't had any luck. Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't already a UEFI bios? It may just be emulating classic bios for you.

Comment: I have never seen a way to convert a non efi bios to efi,

Comment: [Looks like it's possible](http://superuser.com/a/501871/167187), but I don't have any clue how

Comment: @Vinayak looks like a good way to brick a pc.

Comment: @Moab Yes, but only if you don't have compatible MSI or Gigabyte motherboards, I suppose :)

Comment: Your only recourse would be to bug Lenovo to release a UEFI BIOS update for your notebook model and hope that they do.

Comment: @Doc Sorry, I'm not well knowledgeable in this field but that seems like a possibility. Can you explain how I could check if it's a UEFI bios and how to make it not emulate classic bios? Thanks :)

Comment: @Vinayak Hmm, I'll try that. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: Lenovo could not update your BIOS to UEFI even if they wanted to.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you explain more about that to me?

Comment: UEFI has some hardware requirements to implement it.

Comment: @brandon What do you want this change for? Are you trying to boot an OS that isn't cooperating and you perhaps think it's a UEFI (or lack thereof) issue?

Comment: @Doc I'm trying to boot OS X El Capitan onto my PC but it isn't working. I think my BIOS settings are the reason for this, and using Legacy I can't change much. I need to disable VT-d, CFG-Lock, Secure Boot Mode, and set OS Type to Other OS.

Comment: You need a suitable bootloader. I think Chameleon does it. Google OSX86.

Comment: @Doc I'll look into that. So far I've tried to install OSX using clover. Not working.

Comment: @Brandon at any rate, you don't need to goof with your BIOS, you will solve your under-lying problem entirely through careful selection of the appropriate bootloader.

Comment: @Doc I'll do what I can. Thanks for the support :)